# Does it affect to SEO if I use FontAwesome?

Tags: html, css, seo, font-awesome

I coded like this

```
<h1><i class="icon-picture"></i> Pictures</h1>
```

It shows the image of picture with string that's saying `Pictures`

I'm just wondering if google picks up the keyword `Pictures` okay.
Because,`<i class="icon-picture"></i>` is preventing.

How this should be if I concern about SEO

Comment: Should I take space off? it doesn't matter?

Comment: Search engines will read the word 'Pictures' in your H1 tag just fine. The 'i' tag won't stop them doing that. All good. Don't panic.

Comment: Thanks so much:) I'm relived now:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm just wondering if google picks up the keyword Pictures okay.

Yes it does. Why wouldn’t it? The text is plainly, unobfuscated in the document; additionally, you probably don’t even hide it using CSS, right (not that this would matter either)?

> Because, `<i class="icon-picture"></i>` is preventing.

No, Google will probably just ignore this tag altogether.

> Should I take space off? it doesn't matter?

Search engines don’t care about spaces. Leave the space in, you need it for the layout (unless you want to add the margin to all icons, or you add another CSS class to the icon to control the margin individually).

Comment: Thanks:) It's all clear now:) I will check yours as an answer in 10mins